# JFrame objects only show when mousedover

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jbutton

I'm trying to build my own calculator from scratch.
When i run my program as it is now, **some** of the buttons don't show up, until i hover over them with my cursor, and my bounds are all f'ed up. However when i move `window.setVisible(true);` to the beginning of my constructer, every bound of all the objects are placed correctly, but **all** my objects only show once moused-over.

```
package guitest;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.TextField;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;    
import static javax.swing.JFrame.*;

public class Frame implements ActionListener{  


public static int Calculator(int n1, int n2){
    
    return n1 + n2;
}

JTextField num1,num2,ans;
JButton calculate, add, sub, pro, div;
JPanel textFields, actions;

Frame(){
    //Window is being created.
    JFrame window = new JFrame("Calculator");
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setSize(400, 400);
    
    //Creating panel
    textFields = new JPanel();
    actions = new JPanel();
    
    //Adjusting JPanel
    textFields.setBounds(0, 0, 240, 400);
    actions.setBounds(240, 0, 160, 400);
    
    
    //Creating textfields.
    num1 = new JTextField("Number 1");
    num2 = new JTextField("Number 2");
    ans = new JTextField("Answer");
    ans.setEditable(false);
    
    //Creating calculate button.
    calculate = new JButton("Calclulate");
    add = new JButton("+");
    sub = new JButton("-");
    pro = new JButton("*");
    div = new JButton("/");
    
    //adjusting TextFields to my window
    num1.setBounds(30, 20, 200, 20);
    num2.setBounds(30, 60, 200, 20);
    ans.setBounds(30,100,200,20);
    

    
    //adjusting Buttons to my window
    calculate.setBounds(30, 140, 90, 30);
    
    add.setBounds(20, 20, 50, 50);
    sub.setBounds(75, 20, 50, 50);
    pro.setBounds(20, 75, 50, 50);
    div.setBounds(75, 75, 50, 50);
    
    calculate.addActionListener(this);
    
    //adding to my window
    textFields.add(num1);textFields.add(num2);textFields.add(ans);textFields.add(calculate);
    actions.add(add);actions.add(sub);actions.add(pro);actions.add(div);
    window.add(textFields);window.add(actions);
    
    
    window.setVisible(true);

    
    //Setting everything visible
    //textFields.setVisible(true);actions.setVisible(true);
    //num1.setVisible(true);num2.setVisible(true);ans.setVisible(true);
    //calculate.setVisible(true);add.setVisible(true);sub.setVisible(true);pro.setVisible(true);div.setVisible(true);

    
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    String n1 = num1.getText();
    String n2 = num2.getText();
    int a = Integer.parseInt(n1);
    int b = Integer.parseInt(n2);
    
    int c;
    c = Calculator(a,b);
    
    String result = String.valueOf(c);
    ans.setText(result);
    
}

public static void main(String[] args) { 
    new Frame();
    
}  


}
```

[when `window.setVisible(true);` is in the bottom.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkKJv.png)

[when `window.setVisible(true);` is at the top.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QRvHu.png)

[How it is supposed to look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lqnQB.png) (i've hovered over all my objects manually.)

Comment: Stop doing `.setBounds(...)`. Swing was not meant to be used in this way, and by doing this, you're fighting against the library and the layout managers. The cheat solution is to set the layout manager to `null`, but that only perpetuates bad habits and allows creation of GUI's that work on one system only. The real solution is to learn and use the layout managers.

Answer (score 0):

I changed your code and use layouts instead of `setBouds()`.
Swing provide different LayoutManagers and these are used to arrange components in a particular manner. following classes are used to represents the layout managers in Swing:

```
1) java.awt.BorderLayout
2) java.awt.FlowLayout
3) java.awt.GridLayout
4) java.awt.CardLayout
5) java.awt.GridBagLayout
6) javax.swing.BoxLayout
7) javax.swing.GroupLayout
8) javax.swing.ScrollPaneLayout
9) javax.swing.SpringLayout etc.
```

each of them will arrange your components in specific order, which you can read more about it in here ([more details...](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-layout-manager))

```
public class Frame implements ActionListener {

    public static int Calculator(int n1, int n2) {

        return n1 + n2;
    }

    JTextField num1, num2, ans;
    JButton calculate, add, sub, pro, div;
    JPanel textFields, actions;

    Frame() {
        // Window is being created.
        JFrame window = new JFrame("Calculator");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setSize(400, 400);
        window.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        // Creating panel

        // Creating textfields.
        num1 = new JTextField("Number 1");
        num2 = new JTextField("Number 2");
        ans = new JTextField("Answer");
        ans.setEditable(false);

        // Creating calculate button.
        calculate = new JButton("Calclulate");
        add = new JButton("+");
        sub = new JButton("-");
        pro = new JButton("*");
        div = new JButton("/");

        calculate.addActionListener(this);

        textFields = new JPanel();
        actions = new JPanel();

        GridLayout txtBox = new GridLayout(4, 1);
        txtBox.setVgap(20);
        textFields.setLayout(txtBox);
        
        GridLayout actionBox = new GridLayout(2, 2);
        actions.setLayout(actionBox);
        actions.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
        
        // adding to my window
        textFields.add(num1);
        textFields.add(num2);
        textFields.add(ans);
        textFields.add(calculate);
        actions.add(add);
        actions.add(sub);
        actions.add(pro);
        actions.add(div);
        
        window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        
        window.add(textFields);
        window.add(actions);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        String n1 = num1.getText();
        String n2 = num2.getText();
        int a = Integer.parseInt(n1);
        int b = Integer.parseInt(n2);

        int c;
        c = Calculator(a, b);

        String result = String.valueOf(c);
        ans.setText(result);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();

    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't simply provide a code-dump answer but *explain* it as well. What did you think was causing the OP's problem? How does your code solve this problem? Any other information that would be useful to the original poster and (most importantly) all future site visitors with similar problems?